# What is the significance of "org.apache.cxf.resource.method" in CXF?

Tags: java, rest, cxf, jax-rs, interceptor

I was surprised to not get any information on Google about `"org.apache.cxf.resource.method"`. Although, there are a lot of interceptors that use it (in the code that I have been given).

For example this (in a custom `FaultOutInterceptor`):

```
private boolean isServiceResponseRequested(Message message) {
    Method method = (Method) message.getExchange().getInMessage()
            .get("org.apache.cxf.resource.method");
    if (method != null) {
        Class c = method.getReturnType();
        if (c != null) {
            if (c.getSimpleName().equals(
                    ServiceResponse.class.getSimpleName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

[AbstractAuthorizingInInterceptor](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/rt/core/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/interceptor/security/AbstractAuthorizingInInterceptor.java) also has a reference to it.

Could any one mind explaining the significance of "`org.apache.cxf.resource.method`" and how and where to '`set`' it?

**EDIT :**
As a hack to achieve the desired, this is what I've done :

I wrote an `inInterceptor` for `Phase.PRE_STREAM`, configured in `jaxrs:inInterceptors` and in the

```
handleMessage(Message message) 
{
   Message inMessage = message.getExchange().getInMessage();
   Method appMethod = //Logic to determine the method based on the request Url
   inMessage.put("org.apache.cxf.resource.method", appMethod);
}
```

Although, it gives me the desired results, it is totally a hack and doesn't really look correct. Any comments?

Comment: Why do you want to set it?

Comment: There's a custom logic based on whether it is set or not (example above), thus, wanted to know the why's and how's.

Answer (score 0):

`org.apache.cxf.resource.method` Java method selected by CXF to handle the incoming request. This is done automatically by CXF in the Pre-Stream phase, typically by examining the annotations present on the classes and method of your jaxrs:serviceBeans, especially the @Path, @[HTTPMethod], @Produces, @Consumes, etc. annotations.

If you need more fine-tuned control over which Method is being selected by CXF, it might be more appropriate to implement a [ResourceComparitor](http://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest-2.4.x/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/ext/ResourceComparator.html), rather than implementing an interceptor to try to parse this data out of the Message.